# Laravel 5 - Slug implementation

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1, slug

I am hitting a roadblock with slug and so seeking your expert advice.

We have a drivers table, cars table, fleet-owners table.
- drivers have cars
- fleet owners have drivers who have cars
I am trying to create slug as follows:

```
www.example.com/drivers/driver-name  
www.example.com/cars/car-name  
www.example.com/fleet-owners/fleet-owner-name
```

In my webapp, I implemented the slug using [eloquent-sluggable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable) as following with respective the trait.

In the driver model I have create a sluggable method as below

```
protected $sluggable = [
        'build_from' => 'user.name',
        'save_to'    => 'slug',
    ];
```

For drivers, it uses user.name and saves the respective slug and it works as expected for both drivers and cards.

But for fleet owners, I am not able to do this, since for a fleet owner, the driver's name is stored as driver name but I am not able to reference this name or create slug for this.

Comment: Are you wanting to get the fleet owners name from the fleetowner table to be the slug for www.example.com/fleet-owners/fleet-owner-name?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Eloquent Sluggable and am not sure if I understand your database schema, but possibly something like this could work, assuming the Fleet Owner model Has One/Belongs To a Driver model instance.

```
public function getNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->driver->name;
}
```

Then the Fleet Owner model would have a name attribute that Sluggable could make use of:

```
protected $sluggable = [
        'build_from' => 'name',
        'save_to'    => 'slug',
    ];
```

You'll have to make sure there is a slug column on your fleet owner table for this to work.

Comment: Let me give this a try. I thinking your options has triggered another approach i can try. Let me give it a shot. Basically, i should be able to check the name attribute inside sluggable method and set the save_to to appropriate fields. Thanks Josh let me try this out.

Comment: Ok! Let me know how it goes!

Comment: I was able to solve the issue. @Josh Rumbut your solution worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help @Prabesh!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue with the suggestion from Josh below. In the model i created a method

```
public function getNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->driver->name;
}
```

Then in sluggable just use 'name' in build_to and it works.